# Printing with format specifiers in C

Tags: c, printf, format-specifiers

In a class quiz, I was asked to write the output of the below code snippet.

```
x = 1.234;
printf("x=%2d");
```

The variable `x` contains point values so I assumed it to be a float/double type.

In the paper I answered that this code would just simply print the statement within quotes (as `x=%2d`), as in print function it prints whatever within the " " as it is.

But later I ran the code in my compiler to find the output as `x=4199232` (The number varied in different compilers though)
(Edit- I added the compiled code here)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    float x = 1.234;
    printf("x=%2d");
    return 0;
}
```

Can anybody kindly explain me what is really happening here.

Comment: Here undefined behavior happened at least because you forgot to specify an argument for the conversion specifier d.

Comment: If you ran it in a compiler why not show the full sample?

Comment: Didn't your compiler show some hints about missing arguments?

Comment: I tried it now again in an online compiler . It gives a warning as "format %d expects a matching 'int' argument". And it prints random numbers in each compilation.

Comment: Then what did you try to resolve that missing matching int? If your compiler already tells you something is wrong, why waste time and run it? That's a bit like waiting until you crash your a car into a wall instead of stopping it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code has undefined behavior (which explains why *the number varied in different compilers*) because you do not provide an argument of type `int` for the conversion `%2d`.

If you had written this:

```
x = 1.234;
printf("x=%2d", x);
```

The output would depend on the type of `x` which does not appear in the code fragment. If `x` is defined with type `int` or a smaller integer type, including `_Bool`, the output should be `x= 1`, but if `x` has any other arithmetic type, including `float` and `double`, the behavior is again undefined because the argument does not have the expected type for `%d`.

Note also that there is no trailing `\n` in the format string, so the output might be delayed until the end of the program and might not appear at all on some non conformant systems.

In your sample code, the behavior is undefined because of the missing argument to `printf`, but you do define `x` as a `float`, which would be implicitly converted as a `double` when passed to `printf`, invalid for `%d`.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    double x = 1.234;            // only use `float` when necessary
    printf("x=%2d\n", (int)x);   // outputs `x= 1`
    printf("x=%2f\n", x);        // outputs `x=1.234000`
    printf("x=%2g\n", x);        // outputs `x=1.234`
    printf("x=%.2f\n", x);       // outputs `x=1.23`
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: even `float x = 1.234f;`

Comment: @AntoninGAVREL: Whether `float x = 1.234f;` has the same effect as `float x = 1.234;` is an interesting question...

Comment: After further reading and looking at the compiled code, it does not seem to matter, it seem to be only useful for Macros actually

Answer (score 2):

In this statement

```
printf("x=%2d");
```

you forgot to specify an argument for the conversion specifier `d`. So the program will try to output whatever is stored in the memory where the second argument should be.

So the program has undefined behavior.

It will also have undefined behavior if you will specify the second argument like

```
printf("x=%2d", x );
```

because there is used an invalid conversion specifier with an object of the type float.

To output just the format string you should write

```
printf("x=%%2d");
```

Comment: I love the `%%` suggestion!  Here is another ad hoc fix with the preprocessor: `#define printf(s)  printf(s, 42)`